# Can CLion project files be stored in a specified folder by default?

Tags: cmake, clion

I've been using CLion for a little while now, and I quite like it, except that it stores it's prject files by default in my CMake project. I am wondering if I can set a default place it stores it's project files(like compiled executables) in specific directory, per project.(So not one big folder that might interfere with other projects). The reason I want to do that is because I don't like having it in my git project(yes, I know about .gitignore) Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is known as **out-of-source** build, when project's sources are located under *source directory*, but generated files are located under *build directory*. All you need is to setup build directory to be *different* from source one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev How do I do that? And have it do that by default?(I have, make and download lot's of projects)

Answer (score 0):

**To use a different folder for CLion building**

In the CLion menu:

```
Build,Execution,Deployment -> Cmake -> Generation Path
```

Change the value to the folder path you want.

**To include source code from a different folder out of current**

In your CMakeLists.txt, add subdirectory like following:

```
add_subdirectory(<PATH_OF_YOUR_ANOTHER_CMAKE_PROJECT>)
```

Be aware `PATH_OF_YOUR_ANOTHER_CMAKE_PROJECT` can be anywhere on your computer, which does not have to be in your current project folder or one of the sub-folders.

Comment: That's not what I meant. My question is largely about CLion, I want CLion to store it's build files somewhere else then in my cmake project.

Comment: @TimLeijten Updated

Comment: Well, thanks. But that is only for one project, I want it to do that for every project I open. How would I do that?